# How to combine 2 streams in python ffmpeg

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I need to take an audio track from one stream and put it on the video stream.

```
url = ffmpeg.input(video_stream)
aurl = ffmpeg.input(audio_stream)
ffmpeg.output(url, aurl, filename=title).run()
```

I tried to do this, but got an error

> TypeError: argument of type 'Stream' is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [question/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg) on the superuser-platform, you have to map the audio-track , If there already is one in the video-stream.
For the right syntax, you have to look by yourself.